# Google Plus Sign in with app visibility set to circles

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-plus-signin

Using this end point I can find friends of logged in user in circle which user has made visible to my app.

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId/people/visible

But how to ask user to login with visibility set to circles/friends/extended

Comment: I am searching for this too. The default comes only me.